# My C# Settings method, not working to well

Tags: c#, hotkeys

Okay, I have a form called settings that I'm using to set hot key's and other stuff through out my form but the issue is once set you need to restart the app for them to take affect, my code is this:

In main class:

```
public void setHotkeys()
{
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.F4 == true)
        {
            Pvt.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F4);
            MessageBox.Show("checked F4");
        }
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.F5 == true)
        {
            Pvt.HookedKeys.Add(Keys.F5);
            MessageBox.Show("checked F5");
        }
        Pvt.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ghk_startPvt);
        Group.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(ghk_startGroup);
}
```

Settings form class for saving / setting the settings:

```
private void settingsPwn4g3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    settingsLoad();
}
public void saveFields()
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.autoAttach = Autoattach.Checked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.F5 = F5.Checked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.F4 = F4.Checked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
public void settingsLoad()
{
    Autoattach.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.autoAttach;
    F5.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.F5;
    F4.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.F4;

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pwn4g3 Pwn4g3 = new pwn4g3();
        saveFields();
        Pwn4g3.setHotkeys();
}
```

Not to mention this way of doing it is very annoying for over 200 settings this can take days. Any other ideas? I would like to use a variable for set hotkey's then have something where they can press the hot key and set it, rather then 200 check box's for every key on the keyboard.

Comment: So many hotkeys? Are you creating a keylogger application? Variables named pwn? I'm not sure I really want to help out with that.

Comment: No I am not making a key logger, I am making a app that uses a lot of control's not sure why a keylogger comes first to your head, ha. I would like it so people could set hotkey's in the setting's menu for control's but the only way I could think of is with check box's and it's not easy.

Comment: Save a value of type Keys, not bool.

Comment: @HansPassant, I do not have that in the option, thank's. Any more guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's there.  Click Browse at the bottom of the Type dropdownn and drill into the list to find System.Windows.Forms + Keys.

Comment: @HansPassant I've done that but now when I set the hotkey at runtime it keeps the old one and add's another, so if I set it to F5 then F4 both those key's will trigger something, this is my code.

http://pastebin.com/b6rECtST